# Can't create the OSLog activity on Swift

Tags: swift, oslog, cinterop

I want to use the OSLog activities to structure my logs but I stuck with a problem of absence needed activity constants on Swift such as `OS_ACTIVITY_CURRENT` and `OS_ACTIVITY_NONE` and I have an error when I try to create an activity:

```swift
let activity = _os_activity_create(dso, strdup(name), 
OS_ACTIVITY_CURRENT, // Error: Static member 'OS_ACTIVITY_CURRENT' cannot be used on instance of type 'OSLogOutput'
OS_ACTIVITY_FLAG_DEFAULT)
```

`os.activity` framework has descriptions of activity constants without any definitions (but defines the activity flags `OS_ACTIVITY_FLAG_DEFAULT`, `OS_ACTIVITY_FLAG_DETACHED`, `OS_ACTIVITY_FLAG_IF_NONE_PRESENT`):

```
/*!
 * @const OS_ACTIVITY_CURRENT
 *
 * @discussion
 * Create activity and links to the current activity if one is present.
 * If no activity is present it is treated as if it is detached.
 */
```

If we look in ObjC headers `<os/activity.h>` we can find these constants:

```
#define OS_ACTIVITY_NONE OS_OBJECT_GLOBAL_OBJECT(os_activity_t, _os_activity_none)
#define OS_ACTIVITY_CURRENT OS_OBJECT_GLOBAL_OBJECT(os_activity_t, _os_activity_current)
```

It looks like that OSLog is limited on Swift so how to work with OSLog activities or where can I find the constants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found that `OS_ACTIVITY_CURRENT` and `OS_ACTIVITY_NONE` can be dynamically loaded using C-Interoperability since it is not exposed to Swift:

```swift
static let RTLD_DEFAULT = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(bitPattern: -2)
static let OS_ACTIVITY_NONE = unsafeBitCast(dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "_os_activity_none"), to: os_activity_t.self)
static let OS_ACTIVITY_CURRENT = unsafeBitCast(dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "_os_activity_current"), to: os_activity_t.self)
```

But it still looks weird why os.log framework provides API but doesn't the needed constants.

Thanks to https://nsscreencast.com/episodes/347-activity-tracing-in-swift